# how to get value into variable from selected rows cell from DevExpreess GridControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I'm using the DevExpress GridControl where i have to put the values of the selected row's (i.e. one row at a time) cell in variable using C# form. I have a code of getting value from VS2012 inbuilt Data-Grid control, but this code does not work for DevExpress GridControl as follows:

```
string name=dataGrid1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
// this is my code for inbuilt VS2012 datagrid control
```

How can I make it work for the DevExpress GridControl?

Comment: Your code seems confused, you're selecting rows? multiple? or just the one?? you're also changing dataGrid1 but using dataGridView1 ..  You also in your code are not setting value but reading it to nothing

Comment: You need to learn the component you are using by looking at the documentation. For instance, here you are supposed to use one of these https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads, but also they have no `CurrentRow` property, but `FocusedRowHandle` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution, I used `gridView1_FocusedRowChanged()` event that helps me to get value from devexpress GridControl. The code is:

```
private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{    
  strEmpNAme= gridView1.GetDataRow(e.FocusedRowHandle)["Emp_Name"].ToString();
  strDOJ= gridView1.GetDataRow(e.FocusedRowHandle)["DOJ"].ToString();
  strDOB= gridView1.GetDataRow(e.FocusedRowHandle)["DOB"].ToString();
}
```